# Distribution Agent running but subscription does not exist?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

I have an issue where in my replication topology, the distribution agent is running, and says there are no commands to distribute. However, checking the undistributed commands, it shows there are a few hundred thousand left. If I look at the subscriber and choose validate subscription, then SSMS tells me that the subscription does not exist, although I can see it in object explorer.

It is a push subscription, and there are two further push subscriptions that are working fine.

Any idea what could cause this? How can I fix it?